# In angular-cli, how does the "lazy" attribute work to load global libraries?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

By adding them to the *scripts* property of .angular-cli file, one can load global scripts into your app. This example comes from the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-global-scripts):

```
"scripts": [
  "global-script.js",
  { "input": "lazy-script.js", "lazy": true },
  { "input": "pre-rename-script.js", "output": "renamed-script" },
]
```

I am however a bit confused by the "lazy" attribute. When building your app, the to-be-lazy-loaded script is no longer packaged in the scripts.bundle.js file.

But how will the library then be loaded after all? What do I have to do to load the file when necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you configure the "lazy" attribute in the `.angular-cli.json` to load global libraries, you need to "lazy load" the script when needed.  Here is the steps to setup.

1.Configure `.angular-cli.json` in the `apps[0].scripts` array.

```
"scripts": [
    { "input": "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "output": "jquery", "lazy": true }
],
```

> You'll get an `jquery.bundle.js` file in the build output.

2.Load the generated script by appending `<script>` tag in the DOM (`<head>`) lazily.

```
const script = document.createElement('script');
script.src = 'jquery.bundle.js';
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.async = true;
script.charset = 'utf-8';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
```

Comment: This is very useful: so this way we can lazy load global libraries that are only used in a lazy loaded module.

Comment: I'm not sure this will work with output hashing when angular-cli generates your `jquery.bundle.js` as `jquery.8ff49f9cee63643bea4a.bundle.js`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this worked perfectly.
@mfink, when we specify the output as 'jquery', the generated file will always be 'jquery.bundle.js'

Comment: Quick update to this answer, on newer versions of Angular, there's no `.bundle.js` output, it will just be `yourlibraryname.js`

Answer (score 5):

As an alternative to manipulating the DOM in step #2 of Will Huang's accepted answer, it's now also possible to use the dynamic import functionality of `esnext` with TypeScript, as outlined in [this post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-tips-dynamic-module-imports-with-the-angular-cli).

Using this approach, one could then add the following to a lazy-loaded NgModule:

```
import('jquery')
    .then((module: Function) => {
        window['$'] = module;
    });
```