# Is it possible to chunk and lazy load scripts.bundle with angular-cli?

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading, angular-cli

I have some pretty big 3rd party javascripts that I'm adding in `"scripts"` of 
`angular-cli.json`. My `scripts.bundle.js` file is around 7Mb at the moment and I want to be able to split it to chunks and lazy load as I do with my modules.

Is it possible at all?

Comment: I think this is already answered in an existing question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200434/in-angular-cli-how-does-the-lazy-attribute-work-to-load-global-libraries

Answer (score -1):

You can use lazy loading, Angular provide chargue in demand for its modules, use loadChildren

Comment: I'm already using `loadChildren`, but `scripts.bundle.js` is module independent and is loaded on initial page load.