# Angular CLI loading external styles and scripts based on specific modules / pages

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-cli-v6

I'm using Angular 6 but if you have solution with other version I'd love to know how your doing it.

With Angular you have an index.html page which has the bare bones basic structure of the application. Styles and Scripts are then compiled and linked in the index.html page. Where you specify the styles and scripts is in the angular.json. Every module and page then gets the same styles and scripts.

For example, how can one do the following:

**Sign-Up Component**

In this component I need bootstrap, jquery and 3 other external libraries.

**KB Component**

In this component I don't need jQuery or the other 3 external libraries but I do need bootstrap.

How can I configure Angular so that when I go to /sign-up or /kb it only loads external libraries specific to that page?

Comment: If you add the styles into the components style file, and you haven't switched off ViewEncapsulation, then the styles declared in that file will only apply to that component

Comment: @user184994 I do use that however it is not specifically answer my question, I will add more details to my question.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, that's not possible

Comment: @user184994 it appears it is possible, in angular.json file it is possible to mark a script as lazy. Testing it I see that it is not loaded initially. But question then is how to then load it when needed.

Comment: I apologise, I'm obviously out of date. It seems there is an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200434/in-angular-cli-how-does-the-lazy-attribute-work-to-load-global-libraries) that covers it